# something wrong with my Alexnet

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, machine-learning-model

I made Alexnet NN but it had brought out an error

input : image of 32*32*3

output : 10 classes

below is my Alexnet code

```
#alexnet
model_3=Sequential()
#Add the Dense layers along with activation and batch normalization
model_3.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(32,32,3)))
# 1st Convolutional Layer
model_3.add(Conv2D(filters=96, kernel_size=(11,11), strides=(4,4), padding='valid'))
model_3.add(Activation('relu'))
# Max Pooling
model_3.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid'))

# 2nd Convolutional Layer
model_3.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(11,11), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model_3.add(Activation('relu'))
# Max Pooling
model_3.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid'))

# 3rd Convolutional Layer
model_3.add(Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model_3.add(Activation('relu'))

# 4th Convolutional Layer
model_3.add(Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model_3.add(Activation('relu'))

# 5th Convolutional Layer
model_3.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model_3.add(Activation('relu'))
# Max Pooling
model_3.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid'))

# Passing it to a Fully Connected layer
model_3.add(Flatten())
# 1st Fully Connected Layer
model_3.add(Dense(4096, input_shape=(224*224*3,)))
model_3.add(Activation('relu'))
# Add Dropout to prevent overfitting
model_3.add(Dropout(0.4))

# 2nd Fully Connected Layer
model_3.add(Dense(4096))
model_3.add(Activation('relu'))
# Add Dropout
model_3.add(Dropout(0.4))

# 3rd Fully Connected Layer
model_3.add(Dense(1000))
model_3.add(Activation('relu'))
# Add Dropout
model_3.add(Dropout(0.4))

# Output Layer
model_3.add(Dense(500))
model_3.add(Activation('relu'))
model_3.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_3.add(Dense(10))
model_3.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

the error message say

```
Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 11 from 3 for 'conv2d_22/convolution' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,3,3,96], [11,11,96,256].
```

it may concerned to layer size

what is the error of the above code and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

After you pass your input through your first convolutional layer it's size decreases from `32x32` to `6x6`. This is then further decreased by the max pooling layer after that, which decreases the size from `6x6` to `3x3`. It is then not possible to try and apply a second convolution with a kernal size of 11. You should therefore decrease your kernel size in the second layer (and probably also in the first convolutional layer).